# Functional way to build array of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I have a string which is the path to a value in a nested JavaScript object e.g.:

`users.userA.credentials.name`

I would like to split this string into its elements and then create an array with all "sub-paths", like so:

`["users", "users.userA", "users.userA.credentials"]`

Currently I'm solving this the following way:

```
const path = "users.userA.credentials.name"
const currentPath = []
const paths = []

for (const item of path.split('.')) {
  currentPath.push(item)
  paths.push([...currentPath])
}
```

It works fine, but I was wondering, if there is a more functional way (using `map()`, `filter()`, `reduce()` or maybe some `lodash`/`ramda` functions to achieve the same result.

Comment: Do you want `users.userA.credentials.name` as the fourth item too?

Comment: `'users.userA.credentials.name'.split('.').map((item,index,all)=>all.slice(0,index+1).join('.'))`

Comment: `const paths = inits("users.userA.credentials.name".split("."));`. How you implement `inits` (with a loop, map, reduce, whatever) doesn't really matter then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.split()` and `Array.map()` to do it in a more functional way:

```js
const path = "users.userA.credentials.name"
const paths = path.split('.')
  .map((_, i, arr) => arr.slice(0, i + 1).join('.'));

console.log(paths);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to iterate over the substrings and push to an accumulator array, and check the accumulator's previous value (if any) and concatenate it with the new substring:

```js
const path = "users.userA.credentials.name";
const splitPaths = path.split('.');
const initialValue = splitPaths.shift();
const paths = splitPaths.reduce((a, item, i) => {
  a.push(`${a[i]}.${item}`);
  return a;
}, [initialValue]);
console.log(paths);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like this**

Split the string with `.` and than by mapping through it we are joining the elements of temp array according to index.

```js
let str = "users.userA.credentials.name";
let temp = str.split('.');
let op = temp.map((e,i)=> temp.slice(0,i+1).join('.'));
console.log(op);
```

**In case you're interested to do it with regex you can do it like this**

```js
let str = "users.userA.credentials.name";
let temp = [];

let op = str.replace(/\.|$/g,(_,offset)=>{
  temp.push(str.substr(0,offset));
  return _;
})
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce`. Split your path on `.` and then push the subarray after joining on `.` in an accumulator array.

```js
const path = "users.userA.credentials.name",
      result = path.split('.').reduce((r, p, i, a) => {
        if(i)
          r.push(a.slice(0,i).join('.'));
        return r;
      }, []);
console.log(result);
```